# Pip version in Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I updated pip to 21.3.1 in windows shell. But, when I create a new env in pycharm, pip is still old version. How can I make it so that each new venv has an up to date version of pip?

Comment: update pip in the new virtual env

Comment: I will have to do this manipulation every time, sorry but it's not what I want

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the linked duplicates. And thank you for reminding me that I also had this problem. It didn't annoy me enough yet to look for a solution, but now I have one.

Comment: @TheHarryPop you do not have to do it every time. Specify the pip version when you create the env just like you would with the python version. I cannot assist further because you did not say how you are creating the env: Virtualenv, conda, etc.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I apologize for making a double subject, I did not know what terms to use to describe my problem in the search bar

Comment: @It_is_Chris I don't know to select pip version when I create a new env with Virtualenv

Comment: @It_is_Chris It does not work that way. The standard library `venv` module is the default assumption, and it does not provide such an option - it can only be told not to include pip at all. Please see the linked duplicates for details. You need to upgrade it (or install it, if you use that `--without-pip` option) after creating the venv.